# Program to find trailing number of zeroes is giving wrong output

Tags: c

My C program to find trailing number of zeroes is giving wrong output. The loop gets terminated after 1 test case and returns garbage outputs. Here is my code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>
 int main()
 {
      int testcase, no_of_zeroes, i, c, number;
      scanf(" %d \n", &testcase);

      for(i = 0; i<testcase; i++)
      {  
           no_of_zeroes = 0;
           printf(" %d \n", &number);
           c = 5;

           while((number/c) > 0)
           {
                no_of_zeroes += (number/5);
                c *= 5;
           }
           printf(" %d \n", no_of_zeroes);
      }
      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: See [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck... Really, it helps `:)` He would really start quacking when he got to the question of *"What is stored in `number`?"*

Comment: The answers about printf and &number are totally correct.  Also, you should consider the use of the % (MOD) operator for determining whether something is evenly divisible (by 10, 100, 1000, etc...).  I'm assuming you're not counting the trailing zeroes in the actual *string* as a learning exercise, because that's the easier way to do it.

Comment: @David C. Rankin It would start a veritable Quack Overflow. I'll see myself out now. ;-)

Comment: There is no need for a leading space in the `scanf()` format string here, since the `%d` directive skips over whitespace characters anyway. But you should remove the trailing `\n` from the `scanf()` format string (and the trailing space, too). This doesn't do what you probably think it does; it will match whitespace characters until a non-whitespace character is entered, and `scanf()` will not return when ENTER is pressed the first time. Trailing whitespace characters are almost always wrong in `scanf()` format strings,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never initializing `number`, and then you're printing a pointer to it instead of the number itself. Of *course* you're going to print garbage results.

Also, I don't understand how your algorithm is supposed to work. Dividing by five and adding that to the number of zeroes? If I did that with the number 100, that would add 20, but 100 doesn't have 20 trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’

```
 printf(" %d \n", number);
```

you must initialize it, `int number =0;`

or maybe you mean(?):

```
 scanf(" %d \n", &number);
```

Comment: I tried by removing the ampersand sign but the code still gives the garbage values.

Comment: Because you never initialized `number`, so whatever it contains is going to be completely random whether you're reading it correctly or not.